# How to create a new folder inside public folder in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails.

I wanted to know how to create a folder inside a public folder.

I tired the followed command. But it only creates folders outside the public folder.

```
Dir.mkdir('mkdir')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple!

```
Dir.mkdir(Rails.public_path + '/' + 'name_of_your_dir')
```

`Rails.public_path` is a way that you can refer the `public` folder in your rails application.

Comment: Its giving me error `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /test`

Comment: How can I create folder with superuser permission?

Answer (score 0):

`Rails.public_path` returns an **object**. Using the `.to_s` method return the path in a string (needed by `Dir.mkdir`).